# How to solve mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3 error /dev/sda3 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, arch-linux

I am trying to install Arch Linux on a VM in my Windows pc

The Installation guide on the arch website doesn't say how to make the partitions. So I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPYfoFSXB9A) tutorial to do so,

[image]

But when I tried to format these with `# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3`  for mounting I get

`/dev/sda3 is apparently in use by the system; will not make filesystem here!`

`# mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1` gives me

`# mkfs.fat: unable to open /dev/sda1 :Device or resource busy`

Edit: I just noticed something in fdisk /dev/sda
https://i.imgur.com/2XTkcnu_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

I have tried `umount /dev/sda`
`umount: /dev/sda: not mounted.`

also tried `umount /dev/sda{1,2,3}` 1,2,3 each separately
`umount: /dev/sda{1,2,3}: not mounted.`

results from `lsblk /dev/sda`

```
   NANE  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE  RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
   sda      8:0    0 83.3G  0  disk
   |-sda1   8:1    0 400M   0  part
   |-sda2   8:2    0 650M   0  part
   |-sda3   8:3    0 82.2G  0  part
```

results from `df /dev/sda`

```
Filesystem   1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
dev             501152    0    501152   0% /dev
```

Comment: Which guide did you follow ? The official guide list everything including making partitions https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide#Partition_the_disks . Always follow official docs and guides

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide#Installation this one

Comment: That's the same guide i provided.

Comment: Anyway, you should update your question with more information. Where are you running your commands from? Inside the virtual box ?  Did you partition the sda{1,2,3} partitions ?

Comment: I am running the command in Virtual Box. I downloaded the arch iso from here https://archlinux.org/download/ . Yes I did make those /dev/sda{1,2,3} using this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPYfoFSXB9A tutorial on youtube

Comment: do you see `sda3` in the output of `lsblk`, `df` or  `mount`?

Comment: Update your question with the output of ```lsblk```